# Drupal7 - How to display both summary and body on full view?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, entities

It probably has an easy solution, but I couldn't figure out how. I have the original "Article" content type with an image and a summary field. Summary is readily displayed on front page, but in full view, only the body is displayed, but I want to display both the summary and the body. I will have articles where the summary is an eye-catch for the article, but I want to display and style it differently on the full view page too. I am free to edit templates or modify drupal settings so any method vill be fine with me.

Edit: I managed to print the summary with

```
print render($content['body']['#items'][0]['safe_summary']);
```

Is this a good way to print the summary?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `print drupal_render( field_view_field('node', $node, 'safe_summary') );`.

This will also handle [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).